HTTP error: HTTP operation failed invoking https://66ee5dfa3ed5bb4d0bf0c486.mockapi.io/employee/18 with statusCode: 400 with status code: 400
package com.ApacheCamelTest3Task4;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.http.base.HttpOperationFailedException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class HttpsServerRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() {

        String today = LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));

        onException(HttpOperationFailedException.class).handled(true)
                .log("HTTP error: ${exception.message} with status code: ${exception.statusCode}");

        onException(HttpOperationFailedException.class)
                .onWhen(exchange -> exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, HttpOperationFailedException.class)
                        .getStatusCode() == 400)
                .handled(true).log("HTTP 400 Bad Request: Invalid request")
                .setBody(simple("Invalid request: ${exception.message}")).end();

        from("netty:tcp://localhost:9000?textline=true").choice().when(simple("${body} >= 1 && ${body} <= 50"))
                .log("Received number: ${body}")
                .toD("https://66ee5dfa3ed5bb4d0bf0c486.mockapi.io/employee/${body}?bridgeEndpoint=true").unmarshal()
                .json().process(exchange -> {

                    Map<String, Object> employeeData = exchange.getIn().getBody(HashMap.class);
                    String id = employeeData.get("id").toString();

                    String fileName = "D:\\ApacheCamelTest3\\Outputs\\Task4outputs\\" + today + "\\" + id + ".csv";

                    String csvContent = employeeData.get("first_name") + "," + employeeData.get("last_name") + ","
                            + employeeData.get("gender") + "," + employeeData.get("job_area") + ","
                            + employeeData.get("job_desc") + "," + employeeData.get("job_title") + ","
                            + employeeData.get("addr_state") + "," + employeeData.get("addr_city") + ","
                            + employeeData.get("addr_country") + "," + employeeData.get("id");

                    // Set CSV content in body
                    exchange.getIn().setBody(csvContent);

                    // Create the directory if not exists
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelFileParent",
                            "D:\\ApacheCamelTest3\\Outputs\\Task4outputs\\" + today);
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelFileName", id + ".csv");
                }).to("file://D:\\ApacheCamelTest3\\Outputs\\Task4outputs\\" + today + "?fileExist=Override")
                .log("File saved for employee ID ${body}").otherwise().log("Invalid number received").end();
    }
}

sending a random number between 1 and 50 as a parameter to an HTTPS endpoint to fetch details, but the HTTPS request is failing to invoke successfully. While you have the necessary dependencies in place, the issue may be related to several factors. These could include incorrect URL formatting, issues with SSL/TLS certificates, configuration problems within your code or Spring Boot application, or network-related issues that prevent the HTTPS call from succeeding. Despite having the dependencies, the root cause of the failure might involve a missing configuration or an issue with certificate validation or trust, which prevents secure communication with the endpoint.
